# Move record to another tables and then delete it

Tags: php, mysql

i found some questions same like my question, but i didt get the answer for my issue.

I use php and mysql. I have a table of "jobseeker", and the attributes are "id", "name", "CV". I want move a record from "jobseeker" to another table, its name "candidates", and that record remove from "jobseeker". This is my code

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO sortlist (id, name,cv) 

SELECT id,name, cv FROM candidates WHERE id='$id'";

"DELETE FROM candidates WHERE id='$id'";
```

This script only process syntax "INSERT IN TO", not process syntax "delete".

Comment: how is javascript related to this question?

Comment: i think you should better use some status field in table where 1 is "jobseeker" and 2 is "candidates" (only in case tables are same) so instead of deleting row you can just switch id

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to do is, Write a select query to get datas and store in local variable. Then insert and delete from the table.

> $id = $_GET['id'];
>
> $sql = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `id`,`name`, `cv` FROM candidates WHERE id=".$id));
>
> mysql_query("INSERT INTO sortlist(`id`,`name`,`cv`) values($sql['id'],$sql['name'],$sql['cv'])");
>
> mysql_query("DELETE FROM candidates WHERE id='".$id."'");

Comment: mysqli instead perhaps?